# SQLcontext changing String field to Long : Spark 1.5

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have saved my records in to parquet format and am using Spark1.5. But when I try to fetch the columns it throws exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.

This filed is saved as String while writing parquet. so here is the sample code and output for the same..

```
logger.info("troubling thing is ::" + 
    sqlContext.sql(fileSelectQuery).schema().toString()); 

DataFrame df= sqlContext.sql(fileSelectQuery); 

JavaRDD<Row> rdd2 = df.toJavaRDD();
```

*First Line in the code (Logger) prints this:

> troubling thing is ::StructType(StructField(batch_id,StringType,true))*

But the moment after it the exception comes up.

Any idea why it is treating the field as `Long`? (yeah one unique thing about column is it is always a number e.g. Time-stamp).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked metadata?

Comment: I really suggest you to use Scala instead of Java, but you can use an udf and change the data type returned after the operation, in Scala it is very simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to find the solution for the problem.

1. I did not start using SCALA.
2. Did more search and reading and found this:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery

> Notice that the data types of the partitioning columns are
>   automatically inferred. Currently, numeric data types and string type
>   are supported. Sometimes users may not want to automatically infer the
>   data types of the partitioning columns. For these use cases, the
>   automatic type inference can be configured by
>   **spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled**, which is
>   **default to true**. When type inference is disabled, string type will be
>   used for the partitioning columns.

And after changing the mentioned config, issue resolved like charm. :)